# Any member function invoked from a rvalue will return a rvalue?

Tags: c++11

I am wondering if any member function invoked from a rvalue will  return a rvalue in c++11 standard.

for example:

```
Obj foo();
struct Obj
{
    int& operator[](int i)
    {   
        return data_[i]; 
    }
    int data_[20];
};
foo()[1]; // this expression will be treated as rvalue, right? 
          // althrough operator[] return a reference
```

**UPDATE:**

if not, it will be very easy to make the mistake below:

```
decltype(foo()[1]) ai = foo()[1];  //both reference to an obj destroied
decltype(auto) ai = foo()[1];
```

Comment: Nope. It is what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, it'll be an lvalue and if you store a reference to it some place you're on the fast-track to undefined behaviour.

A similar relatively common mistake is storing the result of `std::string::c_str()`:

```
const char* dont_do_this = getStdString().c_str();
```

Regarding your update code, the solution is to be aware of object lifetimes when you could be creating a reference. `decltype(x)` can be a reference type, so you better be sure that if it is, you aren't referencing something which is going to be blasted into oblivion.

Answer (score 2):

No, the result of `foo()[1]` is an lvalue. According to §3.10:

> An lvalue (so called, historically, because lvalues could appear on the left-hand side of an assignment expression) designates a function or an object. [ Example: If E is an expression of pointer type, then *E is an lvalue expression referring to the object or function to which E points. **As another example, the result of calling a function whose return type is an lvalue reference is an lvalue.** — end example ]

(emphasis mine)

On the other hand you can make it so it returns an rvalue reference in that case, by using:

```
struct Obj
{
    int&& operator[](int i) &&
    //                      ^^
    {   
        return std::move(data_[i]); 
        //     ^^^^^^^^^^        ^
    }
    int data_[20];
};
```

or declare the function to be not allowed on r-values by

```
struct Obj
{
    int& operator[](int i) &
    //                      ^^
    {   
        return data_[i];
    }
    int data_[20];
};
```

This will now trigger a compile-time error when you do `bar()[0]`.